# 3D movie optics mathematics

Tags: optics, everyday-life, polarization, parallax

I get the idea that we use two polarized light sources and a parallax rendered film such that the objects seem to resemble true parallax in our eyes once it passes through the polarized glasses, but I'm confused as to why the 3D effect is still coherent for users who are not sitting dead center in viewing angle of the film.

Is there some other compensation being done to allow for viewing in the other angles?

Are the 3D effects seen by people sitting in front row and side seats lower fidelity than the center rows, and why/why not?

If there are any articles/references that go deep into any pertinent math feel free to share them.

Comment: The fidelity does indeed differ with viewing direction and there are no attempts to reduce this. The depth in most scenes is horribly wrong anyway, but most people don't notice. (Next time, pay attention to distant objects which should exhibit no noticeable stereoscopy; the virtual space is often scaled by an order of magnitude just for a 'wow' effect).